# Cohomology classes coming from algebraic K-theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Suppose $X$ is a smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$. I believe there is a Chern class map
$\operatorname{ch}:K_*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to H_{sing}^*(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$ for algebraic $K$-theory. By Grothendieck, $K_0(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is the Chow group, so the image of $\operatorname{ch}$ contains classes coming from algebraic cycles.

What is known about the image of $\operatorname{ch}$ when we include higher $K$-groups? Are there any obstructions against a cohomology class being in the image of this map?

Comment: One obstruction is that the image of $K_{n}(X)$ lies in the "Hodge" part of the mixed Hodge structure, i.e. $\bigoplus W_{2i}H^{2i-n}(X,\mathbb{Q})\cap F^{i}H^{2i-n}(X,\mathbb{C})$. For example, if $X$ is proper then the image is zero as soon as $n>0$.

Comment: In case someone stumbles over this question in the future, Gillet's  "Comparing Algebraic and Topological $K$-Theory" is useful. In particular, from the introduction: "for $K_0$ the image is (conjecturally) described by the Hodge conjecture, while for higher $K$-theory, the image must be torsion."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for being a bit late, but let me try to expand on my comment. An excellent source for this material is James Lewis' "user-friendly" survey article [Lew14].

First recall that for $X$ smooth over a field $k$,
\begin{equation*}
K_{n}(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}\cong\bigoplus_{i}H^{2i-n}_{\mathrm{Mot}}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i))\,.
\end{equation*}
Now suppose $k=\mathbb{C}$. Then we have the (Betti) cycle class map
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}:H^{2i-n}_{\mathrm{Mot}}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i))\rightarrow H^{2i-n}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i))
\end{equation*}
whose image lands in the "Hodge" part of cohomology, i.e. in $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{MHS}}(\mathbb{Q}(0),H^{2i-n}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i)))$. Note that, as per my comment, this latter group is trivial if $X$ is also projective and $n\geq 1$.

Originally it was conjectured that $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}$ is always surjective (the so-called Beilinson-Hodge conjecture, see [Bei86, Conjecture 6]). First note that the case $n=0$ of the Beilinson-Hodge conjecture is equivalent to the Hodge conjecture (clear in the projective case, some work for quasi-projective $X$). But Jannsen [Jan90, Corollary 9.11] found counterexamples in the case $n=1$ (and counterexamples exist for all $n\geq 1$). Indeed, the surjectivity of $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}$ is tied up with the injectivity of certain higher Abel-Jacobi maps (see [Jan90, Corollary 9.10] and [dJL13, Theorem 4.9] more generally), and we know from Mumford that Abel-Jacobi (even $\otimes\mathbb{Q}$) can drastically fail to be injective in codimension $\geq 2$. Note, however, that the Bloch-Beilinson conjectures say that the higher Abel-Jacobi maps $\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ should be injective when $X$ is defined over a number field, so one could imagine that the Beilinson-Hodge conjecture is true for $X$ defined over number fields, and indeed if the Bloch-Beilinson conjectures and the Hodge conjecture are true then $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}$ is indeed surjective when $X$ is defined over a number field (see [Sai09]).

For an example of $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}$ failing to be surjective for $n\geq 1$, consider a K3 surface $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with points $P,Q$ such that $[P]\neq [Q]\in\mathrm{CH}^{2}_{\mathrm{deg}=0}(X)$. Let $U:=X\backslash\{P,Q\}$. Then $\mathrm{cl}_{2,1}:H^{3}_{\mathrm{Mot}}(U,\mathbb{Q}(2))\rightarrow H^{3}(U,\mathbb{Q}(2))$ is the zero map. Notice that $U$ is not defined over a number field here by the assumption, because Beilinson-Bloch predicts that $\mathrm{deg}:\mathrm{CH}^{2}(X)\xrightarrow{\simeq}\mathbb{Z}$ for $X$ defined over a number field (and it is known that $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}\mathrm{CH}^{2}(X)_{\mathbb{Q}}=\infty$ for $X/\mathbb{C}$).

Note as well that along the Milnor diagonal $n=i$ there is evidence that the Beilinson-Hodge conjecture might be true even outside of the situation that $X$ is defined over a number field. See [AK09], [AS07], [Sai04] and [Sai09] for examples and further discussion.

In fact, $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}$ factors through the cycle class map $\mathrm{cl}^{\mathcal{H}}_{i,n}$ into absolute Hodge cohomology:
\begin{equation*}
\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} H^{2i-n}_{\mathrm{Mot}}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i)) @>\mathrm{cl}^{\mathcal{H}}_{i,n}>> H^{2i-n}_{\mathcal{H}}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i))\\ @.     {_{\rlap{\ \mathrm{cl}_{i,n}}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVV\\  @. \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{MHS}}(\mathbb{Q}(0),H^{2i-n}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i))) \end{CD}
\end{equation*}
and the vertical arrow is a surjection (the kernel is the intermediate Jacobian $\mathrm{Ext}^{1}_{\mathrm{MHS}}(\mathbb{Q}(0),H^{2i-n-1}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i)))$). So you are really asking about the image of $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}^{\mathcal{H}}$. There the Beilinson-Hodge conjecture says that the image of $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}^{\mathcal{H}}$ is dense, i.e. $\mathrm{cl}_{i,n}$ is surjective and the induced Abel-Jacobi map
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{AJ}_{i,n}:H^{2i-n}_{\mathrm{Mot}}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i))_{\mathrm{hom}}\rightarrow\mathrm{Ext}^{1}_{\mathrm{MHS}}(\mathbb{Q}(0),H^{2i-n-1}(X,\mathbb{Q}(i)))
\end{equation*}
has dense image. For the reasons given above, if $n\neq 0,i$ then this conjecture is for $X$ defined over a number field.

Finally, one could speculate that the new ideas of Clausen-Scholze (see [Clausen's modified Hodge Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446978/clausens-modified-hodge-conjecture/446992#446992)) have something to say in this setting too. ¯$\backslash$*(ツ)*/¯

---

Bibliography:

[AK09] D. Arapura, M. Kumar, *Beilinson-Hodge cycles on semiabelian varieties*, Math. Res. Lett. 16 (4) (2009), 557-562.

[AS07] M. Asakura, S. Saito, *Beilinson's Hodge conjecture with coefficients for open complete intersections*, in Algebraic Cycles and Motives 2, Edited by J. Nagel and C. Peters, LNS 344 (2007), 3-37, London Math. Soc.

[Bei86] A. A. Beilinson, *Notes on absolute Hodge cohomology*, Contemp. Math., 55, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1986, 35–68.

[dJL13] R. de Jeu, J. D. Lewis, *Beilinson's Hodge conjecture for smooth varieties*, J. K-Theory 11 (2013), no. 2, 243–282.

[Jan90] U. Jannsen, *Mixed motives and algebraic  $K$-theory*, Lecture Notes in Math., 1400, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990.

[Lew14] J. D. Lewis, *Hodge type conjectures and the Bloch-Kato theorem*, Contemp. Math., 608, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2014, 235–258.

[Sai09] M. Saito, *Hodge-type conjecture for higher Chow groups*, Pure and Applied Mathematics Quarterly 5 (3) (2009), 947-976.

[Sai04] S. Saito, *Beilinson's Hodge and Tate conjectures*, in Transcendental Aspects of Algebraic Cycles, Edited by S. Müller-Stach and C. Peters, LNS 313 (2004), 276-290, London Math. Soc.